# Wordpress show page and child navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry this is a really, really, really silly question but how would I go about listing my navigation trail on WordPress.

e.g.

```
About // FAQ // T&C
```

I don't even know what this is called so I don't know what to search in Google.
Thank you

Comment: search for breadcrumbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called *breadcrumbs*. Here's one plugin that let's you do that: http://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-trail/

Comment: Thank you so much! Been pulling my hair out. I can accept the answer in 11 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Wordpress SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin.
it comes with a very good breacrumb function and is the best SEO plugin around.
the breadcrumb call is simple as:

```
<?php if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
   yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>');
} ?>
```